# React Native and Expo bug Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a] FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo

> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a] FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a]'.

> [CXX1410] C:\Users\Abraham\Desktop\Coding\kingdom-tennis-react-native\kingdomTennis\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android.cxx\Debug\1n6a1j3i\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json debug|armeabi-v7a : expected buildTargetsCommandComponents command 'C:\Users\Abraham\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe' to exist

So I am trying to npx expo run:android, and get this error. When building, my main drive on C: ran out of disk space, and stopped. So I moved Android SDK to  D:\Android Studio\Sdk, and updated the jAVA_HOME environment and Android Studio SDK location to reflect this.

Now when running the error, I get the above error and it is absolutely infuriating-- I've already updated my SDK location. How can one fix this?

Updated Android SDK location to my new location D:\Android Studio\Sdk and running npx expo run:android and it crashes.